# Unpacking a container of variant into a variant of containers, combined with the inner variant types

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Some code will help making sense:

```cpp
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using MyType = std::variant<int, float, string>;
using ContainerOfMyType = std::vector<MyType>;
using MySuperType = std::variant<MyType, ContainerOfMyType>;
```

Instead of having `MySuperType` being a `std::variant` of another `std::variant` and a `std::vector` of `std::variant`, I would like to have all types unpacked into a single `std::variant` deriving from `MyType`.

So the expected result in that case would be (written manually):

```cpp
using MySuperType = std::variant<int, float, string, 
                                 std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>,
                                 std::vector<string>>;
```

Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you actually need deriving (as a form of inheritance) or you just used that term loosely?

Comment: I would like to make a `map` that can contains some types and containers of those types. The list of types supported can be extended in the future. So I am looking for having them all defined in a single place and being able to declare the variant that contains both the types and containers of those types in an automatic manner.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your goal, but let's focus on the specific question you asked. Imagine you have a magic alias called `my_super_type_maker<...>` which will be an alias to your *desired* `MySuperType` (the one that's unpacked). What would you put there instead of the `...`?

Comment: As you can see in the description, I have a list of initial types (here defined in the `variant`, `int`, `float` and `string`). I would like to declare a new `variant` type that contains all these base types, plus `vector` of each of these base types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to declare a new `variant` type that contains all these
> base types, plus `vector` of each of these base types.

Template partial specialization should be enough

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

template<class Var>
struct MySuper;

template<class... Args>
struct MySuper<std::variant<Args...>> {
  using type = std::variant<Args..., std::vector<Args>...>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4fGTEbfdT)

Answer (score 1):

With Boost.Mp11, this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
using MySuperType = mp_append<MyType, mp_transform<std::vector, MyType>>;
```

`mp_transform<vector, MyType>` gives you the `variant` of `vector`s of each type, and then `mp_append` concatenates those two together.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EPMTr9TKG).